# Grafana dashboards auto import

Tags: datasource, grafana, dashboard

How can we configure default.ini file in grafana so that when we deploy, it auto installs the exported dashboards.json file automatically

Answer (score 0):

Use [Grafana dashboard provisioning](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/provisioning/#dashboards).

Comment: I have added the dashboard json file in /provisioning/dashboards but on the  logs I am getting this error.  logger=provisioning.dashboard type=file name="Supervisor Dashboards CIM test101" t=2022-08-06T09:45:43.035580624Z level=error msg="failed to load dashboard from " file=/etc/grafana/provisioning/dashboards/wallboard.json error="unexpected EOF"